# PHPmailer, foreach loop in body

Tags: php, foreach, phpmailer

I'm using the PHPMailer script for my site. However, can't figure out how to use a foreach loop to send to the recipient. Tried a bunch of different things.

Basically the code.

```
$mail->Body    = "message" . foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) { }. 
"another message";
```

If I do that, it just errors out. What would the solution be?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a for each loop?

Comment: I guess I should have said, "what are you trying to accomplish?"      Do you want to add all the session variables to the body of the email?

Comment: Just found the answer in this thread. stackoverflow.com/questions/21190297/php-mailer-foreach-in-message-body?rq=1

Have to use $mail->Body .= to continue.

Anyway, I'm coding a webshop, the session contains a load of dynamically generated keys of the different products that I want mailed to the buyer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want send by mail, but if you want send all the session array, it's like this:

```
$mail->Body    = "message";//start of body
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) { 
  $mail->Body .= $key.'  '.$value.'<br>';//each line of session
}

$mail->Body .= "another message";//end of body
```